# Raspberry Pi 3 model B won't boot

Tags: raspbian-jessie, boot-issues

A few days ago I went to boot my trusty Raspberry Pi model 3b (I know, it's a bit outdated) after quite a few months of not using it, and I was going to connect to it in a headless configuration, but I noticed that I couldn't connect. I had to get some other stuff done, so I only came back to it today to investigate. It booted like normal, and it went through all of the normal screens and processes of a boot. I thought that all is well, until I noticed that instead of showing me the Raspbian desktop, I got a blinking cursor. It is not a command line, and I can't type anything in. The green light is also fairly active, blinking every few seconds. Interestingly, while I was off writing this post, the green light has stopped blinking and the flashing cursor has disappeared. It seems similar to this post [Rasberry Pi Black screen after boot wth blinking cursor](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112628/rasberry-pi-black-screen-after-boot-wth-blinking-cursor).

If I can remember correctly, the last few times I was using it, I could not boot into it properly, but only VNC or SSH into the Pi.

I know that I could probably just format the card and flash Raspbian or NOOBS onto it. It is not necessary but it would be nice if there were any way that I can at least recover some of my old files.

Raspberry Pi 3b
Raspbian Jessie
8GB micro SD card

For any reading/writing to the micro SD card, I have a both a Windows and an Ubuntu machine.

Thanks in advance.

---

*I will check back here often, and I will edit my post to include any required information*

---

Comment: On the blinking cursor try *Ctrl* + *Alt* + *F1*. Do you get a login prompt?

Comment: @Ingo Sorry for taking so long to reply, yes I do get a login prompt.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment you can get to the login prompt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
It indicates that only the GUI is not working. Just login and do what is to do to backup and copy your data from the old installation. As *Milliways* suggested in his answer, it isn't worth the effort to try to repair the installation with the outdated, unsupported and archived version **Jessie**.

Answer (score 1):

If you were running Jessie the SD Card has to be nearly 3 years old, possibly more than 4 years.

It is likely the SD Card has just worn out.

If you have a backup (if not why not?) you could try to restore, but Jessie is obsolete, and not worth the effort to recover.

I would suggest you do a fresh Raspbian installation on a **NEW** SD Card.
It is likely you could recover your files from the old SD Card. This is simple with any Linux machine.